# How Can I share text and Image Together on Whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, share

I want to share image and text together with swift.How Can I do That ?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://app")
        let shareText = "Beni Bons'da ekle : \(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!). http://apple.co/29RMfNn"
        let bonsCardImage = UIImage.renderUIViewToImage(bonsCardView)
        let activityItems = [bonsCardImage]
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to share text with image together in iOS on whatsapp, its possible in android but no way in iOS, there are few tweaks to do similar but sharing both at the same time not possible.